# What is the rule for fronting object for emphasis in written English

Tags: grammar, word-order

I've read [some](http://grammar.about.com/od/fh/g/frontingterm.htm) [website](http://www.eltbase.com/notes.php?id=538) about fronting object for emphasis. These are some examples I have got :

*Why she cut her hair* I cannot imagine.

*Strange people* they are!

Despite its small size and slow gait, the wolverine is an effective predator, for  *what it lacks* in speed and size it makes up by strength and endurance.

And my question is :

**Can I front any object? Are there any exceptions?**

Comment: I think your last example is a run-on sentence. -- Quite interesting talking about fronting and inversion is. [Yodaish](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/002173.html) it reminds me of. Be useful for you [Grammar Girl's post](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/yoda-grammar?page=2) would.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first time I've heard the grammatical term, *fronting.* Now I have a word for it. Thank you.

I've tried fronting with a few phrases and find it pretty flexible. But you want a hard rule? With exceptions? As we say,

"What did your last slave die of?" :-)

I'd just advise you to keep using expressions like the ones you quoted. emulating the speech of people or writers whose expression pleases you. Possibly a lot of the expressions you then use will involve *fronting* but unlike you, most of the rest of us won't notice what's fronted and what's not!